# Achieving embossed/slanted/3d border effect with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve following border at the bottom of the element by using only css, and making it as crosbrowser friendly as possible

Sample code, with standard border

```
<div class="object"></div>

.object {
    width: 200px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 20% auto 0 auto;

    border-bottom: 5px solid green; /*Needs to be changed to get effect*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you not want to use box-shadow instead of border? Can you add some HTML/CSS to help maybe?

Comment: make a image. If you want it to be crossbrowser.

Comment: @97ldave Hi I'll add jsfidle with some sample code, but it's very basic. Using box shadow, wouldn't be as cross browser friendly then using border.

Comment: @Mr_Green I'd rather achieve this by code, not a big fan of using many images for design.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup I am saying that there is no way to achieve this which will be cross browser. You have no way but to go with creating image.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a 3D effect with CSS?

Comment: @JonHarding yes, that boxy look

Comment: You could always create an SVG to do the same.  It's code, and an image.  Porque no los dos?

Comment: @Mr_Green What if we say that IE8 should be as far as it goes in terms of crossbrowser friendly, do you think it's achievable? Assuming other browsers should be alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, an example using some pseudo elements and CSS border magic. Note that you have to know the parent element's background color for this to work. Using `:after` this should be [compatible with IE8+](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and fallback gracefully in older browsers, as per your requirement.

This works by understanding that the CSS directional borders are cut at 45° in their direction, in order for you to be able to style the different sides differently (e.g. `border-right` cuts `border-top` and `border-bottom` and so on). By clever usage of border properties and position, you can create the effect of angled shapes.

Creating a *centrally embossed* 3d effect would not need, because of this reason, any other element but using the borders carefully.

[image: central 3d emboss]

Such effect can be achieved by just setting the `border-bottom` to the color and the `right` and `left` to `transparent`.

However, since you want an additional cut, we make use of a pseudo element, giving it a triangle shape and overlapping it over the parent elements border; in this way we get what you need.

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/isixoz/1)</kbd>